profile and release run doesnt work on IOS IPhone but works in debug run
I'm trying to profile run my Flutter application on an IOS device, but I get an error every time I run it. I tried to run it as a release but the same issue occurred.
This the error I get:
Error (Xcode): could not find included file 'Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig' in search paths
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:2:0
Error running application on Farah’s iphone.

To install the necessary iOS dependencies for your Flutter project:
1.Open your terminal.

Navigate to the directory containing your Flutter project.
Change directories to the ios folder within your project by running the command cd ios.
Run the command pod install to install the required pods.


I did this solution but didn't work

try to uninstall pod and then reinstall it

I did, same issue occurred
